# Searching for playlists on soundcloud api returns 500 error

Tags: soundcloud

I'm trying to use the soundcloud api to find playlists with a specific tag. My first step in doing so is pinging the soundcloud api for all playlists. I run the following in my command line to do so (client id replaced for privacy):

```
curl 'https://api.soundcloud.com/playlists.json?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID'
```

This always returns a 500 interval server error, whether I ask for it in json or normal xml:

```
curl 'https://api.soundcloud.com/playlists?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID'
```

However, when I make the analogous request for tracks, it works fine:

```
curl 'https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID'
curl 'https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID'
```

What gives? Is this an error on my side or their side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can grab all playlists.  There must be millions of them, and that is a lot to return.

If you look [here](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#playlists) at the Soundcloud API Docs, they add a playlist id to the URL.

```
$ curl "http://api.soundcloud.com/playlists/405726.json?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
```

Hopefully this helps!